# Cannot access S/4HANA on Premise system via Cloud Connector using SAP Cloud SDK for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sap-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to access an S/4HANA on Premise system via the Cloud Connector and SAP Cloud Platform connectivity service using the SAP Cloud SDK for **JavaScript** (version 1.5.0).

In detail, I have

- Cloud Connector
- connectivity service
- xsuaa service instance
- Application Router (app-router)
- destination
- destination service

which all work as expected. These preconditions are explained by different tutorials (https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/02/a-do-it-yourself-at-home-guide-how-to-connect-a-node.js-app-on-sap-cloud-platform-for-the-cloud-foundry-to-an-s4hana-on-premise-system-securely-via-cloud-connector/, https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/13/part-2-how-to-use-the-sap-cloud-platform-connectivity-and-the-cloud-connector-in-the-cloud-foundry-environment/).

With this setup I have no difficulties accessing an S/4HANA Cloud system.
When using the SAP Cloud SDK for **Java** everything works as expected, i.e. I can access the on premise system. I have sufficient rights on the on premise system. Basic Authentication is used.

Example GET request for retrieving document info records using the SAP Cloud SDK JavaScript:

```
let destination = await useOrFetchDestination({
destinationName: 'MY_DESTINATION',
jwt: 'MY_JWT' });
DocumentInfoRecord.requestBuilder()
.getAll()
.execute(destination);
```

But testing against an on premise system makes the GET request fail with status code 503:

```
ERR Error: get request failed!
ERR     at Object.errorWithCause (/path-to-app/node_modules/@sap/cloud-sdk-util/dist/error.js:14:20)
ERR     at specializeError (/path-to-app/@sap/cloud-sdk-core/dist/request-builder/request/odata-request.js:175:32)
ERR     at /path-to-app/@sap/cloud-sdk-core/dist/request-builder/request/odata-request.js:162:58
ERR     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
ERR Caused by:
ERR Error: Request failed with status code 503
ERR     at createError (/path-to-app/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
ERR     at settle (/path-to-app/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
ERR     at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/path-to-app/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:237:11)
ERR     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:198:15)
ERR     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1139:12)
ERR     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
```

What might I have missed? Are additional HTTP headers necessary to make the request succeed?

**UPDATE**: added destination information to the code snippet and completed error message.

**2nd UPDATE:** The destination config looks similar to this:

```
Name: <MY_DESTINATION>
Type: HTTP
URL: http://...    //this matches the cloud connector host, i.e. in SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit --> Cloud Connectors --> Exposed Back-End Systems
ProxyType: OnPremise
Authentication: BasicAuthentication
User: <USERNAME>
Password: <PASSWORD>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation the **location ID** turned out to cause the problem. It had been set to a specific value on the destination and the cloud connector.
Therefore, the cloud connector would only accept requests providing this property.

There were no errors in the cloud connector's logs. But remotely debugging the application (following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183017/remote-debugging-a-node-js-application-on-sap-cloud-foundry) instructions) brought up this error message:

> There is no SAP Cloud Connector (SCC) connected to your subaccount. Requested opening of a tunnel for subaccount "SUBACCOUNT_ID" and SCC location ID, with default value, that is empty string or simply not configured. Check the configuration on SCC and cloud side.

Using `useOrFetchDestination` from the SAP Cloud SDK JavaScript to retrieve destination information did not return this property which is why it had never been added to a request.

The current workaround is to remove the location ID from both the destination and the cloud connector. Then the requests succeed.

Is there a way to retrieve the location ID of a destination?

**Update:** The location ID can be retrieved from the destination using the `originalProperties` property. If present, it holds the property called `CloudConnectorLocationId`. As described [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cca91383641e40ffbe03bdc78f00f681/Cloud/en-US/d872cfb4801c4b54896816df4b75c75d.html) this value can be added as `SAP-Connectivity-SCC-Location_ID` header to the request.

Thanks Dennis H for your support.

Comment: Currently the location ID is not supported as an explicit property of a destination. However, there is a property called `originalProperties`, that holds the original response from the destination service. so if the location ID is set on the destination, you can find it in `originalProperties`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

To be honest, I'm a little stumped currently. Given that your request works with the Java SDK, I, too, am confused as to why it fails in JS.

Have you tried to query the same exact service in Java? (I.e. are you sure the path mappings in your cloud connector work correctly?)
Can you share your destination config from the cloud cockpit?
Is there any other log output except the error that you've already posted?
Do you have access to the cloud connector logs? (I.e. can you somehow find out where the request fails?

---

**Original answer:**

If this is the exact code you're using:

```
DocumentInfoRecord.requestBuilder()
  .getAll()
  .execute({});
```

Then the request won't work anyway, since you have not provided a correct destination to the `execute` function. You need to either pass a destination itself, e.g.:

```
.execute({
  url: 'https://my.onprem.system',
  ...
})
```

(but I imagine this being quite difficult for an on-prem destination), or provide a destination name the JWT of the current request, e.g.:

```
.execute({
  destinationName: 'my-on-prem-destination',
  jwt: myJwt
})
```

If this is not the code you're using, could you please provide a more representative code snippet and the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Sorry, I should have indicated the destination in the example request. I updated the question.
Yes I first get the destination using its name and the jwt and pass it to the execute function.
I use this code which works fine when accessing an S/4HANA cloud system:

let destination = await useOrFetchDestination({ destinationName: 'MY_DESTINATION', jwt: MY_JWT });
DocumentInfoRecord.requestBuilder()
  .getAll()
  .execute(destination);

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the same service (/API_DMS_PROCESS_SRV/A_DocumentInfoRecord) with the Java SDK where it worked. I added the destination config to the question. I will investigate the cloud connector logs to check where it fails. Unfortunately, this will not be possible before 1st August.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe two more things you can try. 1) Try to set a sap-client header, either as additional property on the destination itself (e.g. sap-client: 001) or as custom header on the request (`.withCustomHeader({ 'sap-client': '001' }). substitute the value for what you need (or even try using an empty string...). 2) You could try to remote debug the application on Cloud Foundry (I can explain how if you're interested, documentation is unfortunately lacking in this regard...).

Comment: Yes, I added it as an answer. The problem was the location ID being set on the destination and the cloud connector. This property was not retrieved with the destination information using useOrFetchDestination and therefore not sent with the requests although expected by the cloud connector.